# Angular JS - Best Practice for Dashboard

Tags: angularjs

I am pretty new to Angular JS and am working on creating a Angular JS powered dashboard within a larger Django application. I have read a lot on Angular but still have a few questions on what is the best way to structure an Angular application that will have many independent widgets within.

I understand there can only be 1 app per HTML document along with typically 1 ng-view call on the page, my question is should I be setting up each individual widget as it's own app or is there a way to render and control multiple modules within a single app?

Currently I have ng-app declared at the top of my document

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="dashboard">
```

Not sure how I would render the remaining widgets if I can only use ng-view once?

I know this question is pretty subjective and there is probably no perfect answer, just looking for some best practices or functional advice.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `ng-include` to have multiple widgets on a page.

Comment: You can create multiple modules using `angular.module('moduleName', [])`.. You can have one app, and multiple modules. Use dependency injection to communicate between different modules.. Read more http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: As someone new to AngularJS that has gone down this road a bit, I wish I had found [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) sooner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is pretty subjective, but using multiple controllers or directives, if done properly, can give you the effect you're looking for.

For example,

```
<html ng-app="my-dashboard">
  <body>
    <div class="Some structuring thing">
      <ng-include src="my-header.html"></ng-include>
    </div>
    <div class="Some other thing">
      <ng-include src="my-sidebar.html"></ng-include>
    </div>

    etc...

  </body>
</html>
```

Then, each section could be its own, stand-alone component.  From there, you can break it down into controllers...

```
<div ng-controller="my-header-text">
  <p ng-bind="title">

  etc...
</div>
<div ng-controller="my-header-login">
  <p ng-click="login()">Login</p>

  etc...

</div>
```

And even further with directives.

```
<my-custom-directive words="user.name"></my-custom-directive>
```

This example is, really overkill, but the point remains; you've got a lot of ways to control granularity as you like.

Personally, these are the rules I like to follow.

1. One `app` per document (as prescribed, and also because it makes sense.)
2. A new controller for every DOM sub-tree that can stand alone; so my login and dashboard clearly have different purposes, and if I wanted granularity, I could break each one into its own controller, and use `services` to properly handle communication with the root of my app.  I could login to any page, not just the dashboard, and a user could use the dashboard even without the option to log in and out (assuming some default case for non-logged in users), so these sections can stand alone and are decent candidates for their own controller.
3. I like custom directives for non-trivial HTML chunks.  It helps readability and reuse; just always try to use the `isolate` scope, and if you can't, question if what you're doing is really a directive.  Write your directive assuming that it could be used not just by your app, but any similar app that included it and followed the correct API.

Comment: This is perfect, I started down the multiple controllers route, glad to get confirmation that was a viable option. Thanks for taking the time to write a well detailed response.

Answer (score 18):

There is a project that implements widgets/dashboard functionality with AngularJS.

Features:

- Adding/removing widgets
- Widgets drag and drop
- Any directive can be a widget

Live Demo http://nickholub.github.io/angular-dashboard-app

Demo source code https://github.com/nickholub/angular-dashboard-app

Dashboard directive itself https://github.com/nickholub/angular-ui-dashboard